# Making a video in an iframe fill browser on mobile device

Tags: html, css, iframe, video, mobile-devices

Hello I have created a very simple page which plays a video that I have which is hosted by wistia. This is working great and I have it filling the browser window. However I was wondering if somebody could show me how to make the video fill the browser on mobile devices even if it overflows to stay in proportion and just a part of the video displays. I do not mind as it serves as a background.

Thanks in advance

***CSS IN HEAD SECTION***

```
<script src="//fast.wistia.net/assets/external/E-v1.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
        body, html
        {
            margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
        }

        #content
        {
            position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px; top: -15px;
        }
    </style>
```

***HTML IN BODY SECTION***

```
<div id="content">
        <iframe src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/qnca9gdlv5?videoFoam=true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen width="640" height="388"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to to add to the css id "content" a minimum height?

```
#content {
    min-height: 1920px;
    min-width: 1108px
}
```

In this way the video size should be extended to the full dimensions of a mobile device.
Let me know if it works.

Comment: no joy... its no different... but thanks for giving it a try for me :)

Comment: What are the dimensions of the video in px? Try to substitute the height and the width as I did in the answer.

Comment: if you take a look at www.cambridgedesigncompany.com/beach.html you will see the page... The dimensions are set to 100%.